# What is the X & Y for a Tkinter perfect square?

Tags: python, tkinter

Quick question, when you put in something like `padx = 10, pady = 10` into a Label/Button it will give you a rectangle.

Does anyone know what X by Y is a perfect square?

Comment: pady and padx just move the widget so I am also a bit confuse as to what You mean by perfect square here. a perfect square has all sides the same

Comment: Oh, uhh I think I got it I was using padx and pady instead of height  and width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The width and height of a label is dependent on several factors - the font being used, the image being used, borderwidths, padding, etc. Many of those are symmetrical,  however.

If you want a perfect square, you need to either start with an image   (which causes `width` and `height` attributes to be treated as pixels), or a font where the characters are as wide as they are tall (even if you don't have any text).

Put another way, without an image `height` and `width` refer to a number of average size characters. Unless your font is the same in the x and y axis, these attributes will resolve to a different number of pixels. If you include an image in the label -- even just a one pixel image -- then `width` and `height` are in units of pixels rather than characters.

Here's an example that creates a square label using an image:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("200x200")

image = tk.PhotoImage(width=1, height=1)
label = tk.Label(root, image=image, width=50, height=50, background="red")
label.place(relx=.5, rely=.5, anchor="c")

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: I tried ```width = 50, height = 50``` and it still doesn't work. It just gave me  a bigger rectangle.
I also have no text or images.

Comment: @Lloyd: like the answer says, you either need a font where the characters are as wide as they are tall (even if you have no text), or you need to have an image.

Comment: @Brylan Oakley Ok I will add a text.

Comment: @Lloyd: you're probably not going to want to add text, since most fonts are not rectangular.

Comment: I just found a square character and adjusted the color to be the same as the background and this worked...

Comment: So this explains why setting width and height of an empty button to 10 does not give a square button?

Comment: @CoolCloud: Not in the specific case you mentioned. Setting the width of an empty button to 10 makes it 10 characters wide but only one character tall.

Comment: @BryanOakley I don't understand, I am setting height and width to the same number, why is it just effective for the width.

Comment: @CoolCloud: I'm sorry. I missed that you're setting the width and height. As the answer (and documentation) says, `width` and `height` are relative to the width and height of a single average character specifically, the character '0') unless you use an image. Unless your characters are square, the button won't be square.

Comment: @BryanOakley Oh okay, so what does this character mean? The default font size?

Comment: @CoolCloud: Every font is made up of a series of glyphs. Each glyph has a width and a height. For the vast majority of fonts, characters are taller than they are wide. Tkinter uses the character '0' when doing size calculations.

Comment: @BryanOakley So just to confirm: The default fonts, height and width of '0' is taken into consideration? Thanks

Comment: @CoolCloud: the measurements being used are for the actual font for the widget. If the widget hasn't specified a font, then yes, it's based on the default font font that widget.